OpenIdDict - ApplicationID and AuhtorizationId in Tokens
I am implementing my data layer for a project I am involved.
I wonder why the Token entity has a reference to the Application Entity and also to the Authorization Entity since the Authorization Entity already has a reference to the Application Entity.
Can a Token be released for an Application different than the one that holds the Authorization?
Thanks.
Stefano.
